# Random BSOD with Windows but not with Ubuntu

Tags: windows, bsod

I know this is a problem everyone is having and there are also so many threads etc. opened about this. However, I have actually tried all of the solutions that are posted on the web but haven't got success as of yet. The problem I am facing right here is that I randomly get a BSOD/Blue screen for no reason and only in windows. Before that I had Ubuntu and everything was fine. I have tried swapping rams sticks and all of that but that didn't help. If you have any questions or have anything to ask just comment, if you just could give me a tip or advice about this that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! BTW: I also have updated everything to the latest drivers on the web. :)

**P.S. This was a custom build pc (rig), in case you wondering here are the specs:**

**Processor :A8 3850
2.9ghz, 4.0 mb total cache**

**Motherboard: socket FM1, Gigabyte A55M-S2V**

**Ram: 2x2gb (kit) DDR3 Crucial**

Thank you very much.

Comment: When it BSODs, have you tried to recover any of the dump information or gotten the crash's stop error number? What version of Windows? What prior recovery options have you taken; what system changes have you recently made? Have you tried reverting to an earlier restore point?

Comment: Currently I have windows 7 home premium 32bit installed. Unfortunately, I could not catch the crash number since it was going to fast :( Also, I do not have any programs or anything installed just drivers so there are no earlier restore points, recovery was also unnecessary at this point since it is fresh install. Reinstalling windows 7 doesn't make a change and the error remains, however swapping to an other OS solves the problem. Anyway, thank you very much for your response :) Hope this helps

Comment: [Disable automatic restart](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic74644.html) and come back with the information from the blue-screen, The instructions are for XP but they are the same for newer versions too.

Comment: Preferably you can open up a new answer because this might take a while. Thank you very much for your solution, will definitely try it out straight away and I will of course tell you the result as soon as I have done this. Thanks :)

Comment: Step 1: turn off automatic restart upon system failure. Right click computer>properties>advanced system settings>startup and recovery.  Step 2: check  C:\Windows\minidump If it is empty return to step one and make sure the path is set and it is not disabled.

Comment: I had an issue with Windows having trouble with a failing HDD (sporadic BSODs and slow write speed or fails) that Ubuntu could cope with or wasn't as affected by; have you run a disk utility from the manufacturer of the hard drives to verify their viability?

Comment: @ShadAsinger you can just delete your own question and re-ask it later once you have the information.

Comment: Linux is able to ignore HDD and memory errors, while Windows just chokes on them. So I would say the most likely cause for this is that either your memory or HDD are damaged. If it's the HDD, just use a tool like HDD Regenerator or HDAT2 and you're set.

Comment: Are you by chance using an SSD?  If so, is your SATA controller set to AHCI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need more information. You say you got a BSOD. Ok, but what code if any did it give you?

You can do things like:

1. Download the debugging tools for Windows. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009
2. Run Windbg.exe (elevated) and open up the memory.dmp file that the BSOD should have created. (Look up how to enable it if it didn't.)
3. IAW http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503, set the symbol path like so: .sympath http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
4. Run .reload in Windbg.
5. Run !analyve -v in Windbg.

The output can give you some idea of what went wrong. Maybe not a ton, but some. Like if it was due to a driver, for example.

Most of the above shouldn't be necessary though, there should be a Windows Event log entry that contains at least the memory addresses or whatnot. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/unexpected-windows-shutdown-bluescreen/b35cf1d2-f72f-4d98-b94a-25acd1737c7d

Actually you know what? Try this thing: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html It's free and I just tried it on a machine I have BSODs on (It has a known problem with the amount of RAM installed in it, I'm just too lazy to fix it.) and it picked everything up.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for your detailed answer. I haven't had time to pick up on all the answers since I was away. I will try all these good tips out in a bit and will try report it you :) ... if you don't mind. Btw. Thanks :D

Comment: Sure, no problem. In fact, if you can use pastebin or something similar to put the minidump online I can take a look, though I have to warn you this is NOT what I do for a living so it would only be pure luck that I was able to tell you something useful. :)